# Values keep resetting when changing an object of a vector of objects

Tags: c++

I created two classes. The first class take in a string as a param which it sets to the name of the person.

The second class is where I create an object of a vector which holds objects. I need this object to make additional functions later on in the code. (this code is an example of the problems I have with my main code)

In the main section I create objects of both people and person which I try modify.

after modifying the code, it reverts.

I have tried taking everything by reference but it does not work. I am not sure of what I am doing wrong.

The first class which creates the objects ( these will be stored inside the vector)

```
class person {
    // Private
    string name;
public:
    // Constructor
    person(const std::string& n) : name(n) {};

    std::string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(const std::string& n) {
        name = n;
    }

};
```

This is the Class to create object that takes vector of obejcts.

```
class people {
     // Private
     vector<person> _peeps;
public:
     // Constructor
     people(const vector<person>& r) : _peeps(r) {};

     vector<person> getRobots() {
           return _peeps;
        }

    void addRobot(const person& r) {
         _peeps.push_back(r);
    }
};
```

This is the main section of the code where I create the objects and print the outputs.

```
int main(){

      string arr[5] = { "john", "eddison", "jeves", "elenour", "curtis"};

      vector<person> rob;

      for (auto x : arr) {
            rob.push_back(person(x));
       }

       people robots = people(rob);

    for (person &x : robots.getRobots()) {
        cout << x.getName() << ", ";
    }

    cout << "\n2\n";

    for (person &x : robots.getRobots()) {
        x.setName(x.getName() + "x");
        cout << x.getName() << ", ";
    }

    cout << "\n3\n";

    for (person &x : robots.getRobots()) {
        cout << x.getName() << ", ";
    }
}
```

This is the output for the code

1 (where I output all values inside the vector of objects)

2 (where I edit all values inside vector)

3 (Test to show if values have changed)

> 1
>
> john, eddison, jeves, elenour, curtis,
>
> 2
>
> johnx, eddisonx, jevesx, elenourx, curtisx,
>
> 3
>
> john, eddison, jeves, elenour, curtis,

Why is the output at 3 not the same as 2?

Comment: How does this output differ from your expectations? I'm not clear what the problem is.

Comment: `getRobots()` returns a temporary vector that is a copy of `_peeps`. Then you modify that copy. Then that copy is destroyed. `_peeps` member remains unchanged. When you call `getRobots()` again next time, you get a fresh copy of that unchanged vector.

Comment: Change `vector<person> getRobots() {` to `vector<person>& getRobots() {` here is that online: [https://ideone.com/VGInXm](https://ideone.com/VGInXm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return copy instead of reference,

use

```
const std::vector<person>& getRobots() const {  return _peeps; }
std::vector<person>& getRobots() {  return _peeps; }
```